# C# HttpPostedFileBase object.ContentType property check for supported type validation

Tags: c#, validation, httppostedfilebase

I am trying to validate file upload by supported file types, for now I am comparing ContentType property with list of supported file types like "text/xml" "application/x-zip-compressed" etc. I have found these strings simply by trying to upload various files and checking the value of ContentType property in debug mode.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Because it is pain to check ContentType property for 20 different file types and it is huge work to find those files or create convert from other types whatever.

Is solution to compare just by file extension?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContentType is a pretty sound way of comparing (on the server side).

You can get a list of various MIME types here
http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

If you are supporting the certain file type, then you take on the job of converting it too, so what is the question really?

You only need to see if the file uploaded is one of the types you support. So that's a list you can stored in a HashSet and then when you receive and uploaded file, simply check against the HasSet

```
hashSet.Contains(contentType)
```

Comment: link is no longer working...  for Mime types err i mean media types http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types